# Old TV series about a blonde alien girl who can read minds and a man who must help her

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv, telepathy

This show is almost certainly from the 80s, maybe early 90s. A long-haired, slender blonde young woman arrives on Earth escaping from some organization, I think, and encounters a man who has to help her. (He might be from the CIA or a cop?)

As soon as they meet, he has sexual thoughts and she acts offended, revealing that she can read minds.

In one episode, the guy is in some kind of music class and the teacher asks the students if the bell in the school makes music; another student says that it does, based on a dictionary definition of music, which leads the protagonist to realize he's an alien as well.

Comment: Your question has been closed as a Duplicate. This is not a censure, merely policy for [tag:story-identification] questions that share the same answer. You will still receive points for upvotes, and people can comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're remembering the 1988, two-part television movie, "Something is Out There" The miniseries also spawned a short-lived weekly series.

[image]

The description below is from Wikipedia:

Jack Breslin (Joseph Cortese) is a police officer investigating brutal murders in which organs have been removed from the victims with (by human standards) surgically impossible speed. He learns that the crimes are being committed by a monstrous alien insectoid prisoner known as a xenomorph, possessing shape-shifting and physical possession abilities, who has escaped from an alien prison starship passing by the solar system, and he teams up with a beautiful medical officer from that ship, Ta'Ra (Maryam d'Abo), to track down the villain. Ta'Ra has assorted superhuman abilities, including telepathy and superhuman agility, which come in handy during the mission.

Comment: Yes! Yes! You were so fast.

The girl is definitely her, and using Google Images I found this https://comic-watch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/Something-is-Out-There-1.jpg.webp which is from the series I remember. I think what I saw is the show made after the movie because I don't recognize the guy in the poster as the protagonist. 

I see I was misremembering some crucial stuff but you identified it anyway. Thank you!